# What causes `newuidmap` to be dissallowed in new user namespace?

Tags: linux, namespace, uid

I expected

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

to be the output of both

```
$ rootlesskit id
```

```
$ unshare -U bash -c 'newuidmap $$ 0 '"$(id -u)"' 1; id'
```

however the somewhat more verbose `-x` command

```
$ unshare -U bash -xc 'newuidmap $$ 0 '"$(id -u)"' 1; id'
```

yields instaed

```
+ newuidmap 41372 0 1000 1
newuidmap: uid range [0-1) -> [1000-1001) not allowed
+ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)
```

Why makes `newuidmap` think that mapping a user's `uid` to `0` in an new user namespace would be dissallowed?

My understanding of info contained in [man 7 user_namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) is that any user (assuming `CONFIG_USER_NS_UNPRIVILEGED` is configured) can do an `unshare` or `clone` in order to create a new user namespace (setting the flag `CLONE_NEWUSER`).

Now I now that the main "additional value" of `newuidmap` is to map the ranges specified in `/etc/subuid` however, I `strace` the working `rootlesskit` shows:

```
[pid 35921] execve("/usr/bin/newuidmap", ["newuidmap", "35909", "0", "1000", "1", "1", "200000", "65536"], 0xc000002480 /* 44 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[....]
[pid 35921] openat(3, "uid_map", O_WRONLY) = 5
[pid 35921] write(5, "0 1000 1\n1 200000 65536\n", 24) = 24
```

eventually

Also of course it is totally possible to do the mapping even without `newuidmap`

```
[user1@host tmp]$ cat > unshare.c << EOF
> #define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd_uidmap;
    char mapping[255];
    sprintf(mapping,"0 %ld 1\n",(unsigned int) geteuid());
    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER) == -1)
    {
        puts("error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fd_uidmap = open("/proc/self/uid_map",O_RDWR,NULL);
    write(fd_uidmap,mapping,strlen(mapping));
    close(fd_uidmap);
    execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
    return 0;
}
EOF
[user1@host tmp]$ gcc unshare.c -o unshare
[user1@host tmp]$ ./unshare id
uid=0(root) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)
```